# Linear regression: Good results for training data, horrible for test data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am working with a dataset of about 400.000 x 250.
I have a problem with the model yielding a very good R^2 score when testing it on the training set, but extremely poorly when used on the test set. Initially, this sounds like overfitting. But the data is split into training/test set at random and the data set i pretty big, so I feel like there has to be something else.
Any suggestions?

## Splitting dataset into training set and test set

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(['SalePrice'], 
axis=1), df.SalePrice, test_size = 0.3)
```

## Sklearn's Linear Regression estimator

```
from sklearn import linear_model
linReg = linear_model.LinearRegression()    # Create linear regression object
linReg.fit(X_train, y_train)                # Train the model using the training sets

# Predict from training set
y_train_linreg = linReg.predict(X_train)

# Predict from test set
y_pred_linreg = linReg.predict(X_test)
```

## Metric calculation

```
from sklearn import metrics
metrics.r2_score(y_train, y_train_linreg)
metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred_linreg)
```

R^2 score when testing on training set: 0,64

R^2 score when testing on testing set: -10^23 (approximatly)

Comment: Have you tried cross-validation (using different parts of data for training and test multiple times). Maybe the current distribution of data in train and test doesnt allow model to learn about the data into test (because similar data is not present in train).

Comment: Have you tried to apply any feature transformation/preprocessing method? e.g. MinMaxScaler and then use cross-validation to evaluate the performance ?

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with Mihai that your problem definitely looks like overfitting, I don't necessarily agree on his answer that neural network would solve your problem; at least, not out of the box. By themselves, neural networks overfit *more*, not less, than linear models. You need somehow to take care of your data, hardly any model can do that for you. A few options that you might consider (apologies, I cannot be more precise without looking at the dataset):

- Easiest thing, use regularization. 400k rows is a lot, but with 250 dimensions you can overfit almost whatever you like. So try replacing LinearRegression by Ridge or Lasso (or Elastic Net or whatever). See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html (Lasso has the advantage of discarding features for you, see next point)
- Especially if you want to go outside of linear models (and you probably should), it's advisable to first reduce the dimension of the problem, as I said 250 is a lot. Try using some of the Feature selection techniques here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html
- Probably most importantly than anything else, you should consider adapting your input data. The very first thing I'd try is, assuming you are really trying to predict a price as your code implies, to replace it by its logarithm, or log(1+x). Otherwise linear regression will try very very hard to fit that single object that was sold for 1 Million $ ignoring everything below $1k. Just as important, check if you have any non-numeric (categorical) columns and keep them only if you need them, in case reducing them to macro-categories: a categorical column with 1000 possible values will increase your problem dimension by 1000, making it an assured overfit. A single column with a unique categorical data for each input (e.g. buyer name) will lead you straight to perfect overfitting.
- After all this (cleaning data, reducing dimension via either one of the methods above or just Lasso regression until you get to certainly less than dim 100, possibly less than 20 - and remember that this includes any categorical data!), you should consider non-linear methods to further improve your results - but that's useless until your linear model provides you at least some mildly positive R^2 value on test data. sklearn provides a lot of them: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_ridge.html is the easiest to use out-of-the-box (also does regularization), but it might be too slow to use in your case (you should first try this, and any of the following, on a subset of your data, say 1000 rows once you've selected only 10 or 20 features and see how slow that is). http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#regression have many different flavours, but I think all but the linear one would be too slow. Sticking to linear things, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#regression is probably the fastest, and would be how I'd train a linear model on this many samples. Going truly out of linear, the easiest techniques would probably include some kind of trees, either directly http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#regression (but that's an almost-certain overfit) or, better, using some ensemble technique (random forests http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forests-of-randomized-trees are the typical go-to algorithm, gradient boosting http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#gradient-tree-boosting sometimes works better). Finally, state-of-the-art results are indeed generally obtained via neural networks, see e.g. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html but for these methods sklearn is generally not the right answer and you should take a look at dedicated environments (TensorFlow, Caffe, PyTorch, etc.)... however if you're not familiar with those it is certainly not worth the trouble!

Comment: This is very clear and comprehensive guideline. Two add-on's 1) on point 3 I would also add scaling of the features to the zero mean and unit variance (using either [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) or [RobustScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html). Linear models are affected by the difference in scale, if I remember right. 2) On the last point i would recommend LightGBM/CatBoost or XGBoost instead of the sklean GBM implementations, as they are much faster

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi many thanks for adding details to my answer, indeed omitting to recall centering and rescaling data was a big miss on my side, as they are very much needed! Also thanks for pointing out the better boosting implementations, since I was only aware of XGBoost, that part of the answer will be useful to me, too :-)

Comment: Just for the record, there are several benchmarks flying around, that show that on CPU LightGBM and CatBoost outperform XGBoost (there are benchmarks that XGBoost still is faster on GPU than LightGBM at least, but I do not train them on GPU's so I can not share personal experience). And all three are much faster than sklearn's implementation. So it is very useful to play around with those packages.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.
I have already done scaling of the feature variables. Switching to Ridge did however yield a much better result, with almost no difference between the training data and the test data :)